# Laravel jenssegers/laravel-mongodb model properties are not cleared on changing database connection and run another query

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I'm using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb with Laravel 5.6 which is great, but I have a strange issue.

I have a model with this static function:

```
Class Trigger {
....
public static function onCustomer(User $customer)
{
        config(['database.connections.' . $customer->server . '.database' => $customer->database]);
        return self::on($customer->server);
}
}
```

If I do this:

```
$result = Trigger::onCustomer(User::find('573072804d358b06308b4567'))->get()
```

it will return a collection with 2 objects - which is correct!

Then if I do this:

```
$result = Trigger::onCustomer(User::find('598e003a1736736644debbc7'))->get()
```

it will return the same collection as above, but user 598e003a1736736644debbc7 does not have any records in database.

If I close php artisan tinker and run second command again it will return empty collection. Which is correct. Afterwards if I run the first command written above, it will return empty collection, even if it has 2 objects in it.

Even if I run unset($result) or $result = null and run command again it will not bring correct result.

How can I proper destroy the variable or Trigger class object so at a second run it will bring correct results?

I have tested this both in php artisan tinker and browser. The result is the same.

Obvious, if I run the above commands in separate php instances it will work fine. It must have something to do with model cache or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to my own question, the problem is that I changing the config dynamically, but the connection instance still exists. I will have to force the connection to reconnect to load the new config.

So the code must be like this:

```
public static function onCustomer(User $customer)
{
    DB::purge($customer->server);

    config(['database.connections.' . $customer->server . '.database' => $customer->database]);

    DB::reconnect($customer->server);

    return self::on($customer->server);
}
```